# how to get all data from GridView before the paging occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, sqldatasource

I have `GridView` that have a `SqlDataSource` as DataSource. The `GridView` has its `PageSize` property set to 10 and `AllowPaging` to true. What I am trying to achieve is to get all rows data from the `SqlDataSource`.

I have tried to get the data on `Page_PreRender` but I get 0 for row count on the gridview. There are 100 rows actually in the gridview.

Here is the current code :

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvBills.AllowPaging = false;
        int t = gvBills.Rows.Count;
        gvBills.AllowPaging = true;
    }
```

Any suggestions or guidance regarding how to fetch all that data from the gridview would be helpful.

**Update**

when i use

```
protected void gvBills_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvBills.AllowPaging = false;
        int t = gvBills.Rows.Count;
        gvBills.AllowPaging = true;
        gvBills.PageSize = 350;
    }
```

i get the correct number of lines but the gridview show all the rows in one page.

this is my gridview control

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvBills" CssClass="gridtable" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" DataSourceID="DataSourceBills" 
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="false" AllowSorting="true"
        OnRowDataBound="gvBills_RowDataBound" EmptyDataText="<%$ Resources:general_tags, NoDataFound %>" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="350">
```

and my sqldatasource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSourceBills" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EnergyManagementConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="usp_BCPD_SearchBillsHistory" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        DeleteCommand="usp_BCPD_DeleteData" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>           
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="UD_ID" SessionField="UserID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="BillType" ControlID="hfld_BillType" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="SL_ID" ControlID="hfld_SL_ID" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />                
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="CD_ID" ControlID="ddlConsumer" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />   
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="CUR_ID" ControlID="ddlCustomer" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />             
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="BSD_ID" ControlID="hfld_BSD_ID" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Consumers" ControlID="hfld_ArrFinalConsumersSearch" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Channels" ControlID="hfld_ArrFinalChannelsSearch" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Customers" ControlID="hfld_ArrFinalCustomersSearch" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="strFromProductionDate" ControlID="hfld_FromProductionDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="strToProductionDate" ControlID="hfld_ToProductionDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="strProductionDate" ControlID="hfld_ProductionDate" PropertyName="Value" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Reading" ControlID="ddlReadingFlag" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="strFromReadingDate" ControlID="hfld_FromReadingDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="strToReadingDate" ControlID="hfld_ToReadingDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="BillStatus" ControlID="ddlBillStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="BPET_ID" ControlID="ddlBillError" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustomerType" ControlID="ddlCustomerType" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ChannelDisplayType" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="AdditionalParameter" ControlID="hfld_AdditionalParameter" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Try putting this code in `Page_Load`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're trying to get 'all data' from your gridview. It looks like you're trying to get the count of all the rows. Is that right? Or was that just a test?

Comment: I need to get all data , the count is just for the example.

Comment: @sr28 - Its the same thing as far as checking what is being received is concerned.

Comment: In page load i get 0 rows

Comment: Try your code in gvBills_RowDataBound event...

Comment: The row databound run just for row in page.

Comment: What's the reason you need to do this? Maybe there's another way to achieve what you want

Comment: the user select rows to export(via client side ajax) i need to have all the rows id's (even those in other gridview page) in a hidden so i can pass it to the ajax, if he select to export all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick something like this (where ds1 is your sqldatasource) into the Page_Load event:

```
DataView dv = (DataView)ds1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = dv.ToTable();
```

You can then get the data out of 'dt'.

***UPDATE***

If you want to get the data from the Gridview rather than the sqldatasource then you can do the following:

```
private DataTable getGridData()
{ 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("RowId", typeof(Int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Title", typeof(String)));
    //Add more data columns as needed.

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvBills.Rows)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = (int)row.FindControl("RowId");
        dr[1] = row.FindControl("Title").ToString();
        //Add more values if more columns are added / needed.

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Call this method from where ever you need to use the data.

***UPDATE 2***
 To avoid only returning the rows only on the current page turn of paging like you did previously in your other code and then databind again before running through the rows:

```
gvBills.Allowpaging = false;
gvBills.DataBind();
```

Comment: when i do it i get the data but the gridview is empty

Comment: @eyalb - This code shouldn't impact your gridview displaying. This simply gets what's in the sqldatasource and puts it into a datatable for you to use.

Comment: i get the correct numbers of rows but in the gridview i see no data.

Comment: @eyalb - then there must be a separate issue with how your gridview is displaying as this code will not effect how your gridview displays. Are you saying that if you simply comment out this code that the gridview displays correctly?

Comment: @eyalb - I've given an update to try something else.

Comment: when i call getGridData() on page_load i get the number of rows from the last search. and even then just for the current page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75706/discussion-between-eyalb-and-sr28).

Comment: @eyalb - if you're going down the route of getting the data from the gridview using the foreach loop, then you will need to turn paging of and databind the gridview again to make sure you have all the data rather than just those on the current page. Once you've got all the data you want you can then put the paging back on an databind again.

Comment: it's work but every time i do a databind the rowdatabind is runing on every row. maybe it's take to much resource.

Comment: @eyalb - this event would fire whenever you databind. Have you got a lot going on in this event?

Comment: no, the main thing is not going to the server to select the data again.

Comment: @eyalb - I'm not sure I understand. Are you databinding in the foreach loop or beforehand?

Comment: it's ok now, i get the grid to work fine, and have all data in a datatable.

Comment: Great. I hope I helped.